# How to query multiple XML files?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xpath, xquery

I will be getting tens of thousands of XML documents that I'll need to query. The queries need to encompass all the XML files, not just querying individual files. For example, I might need:

- Return the `<name>` value from the XML file whose `<publish_date>` is the most recent

What technologies or approach can I use for this scenario?

- Loop through each XML file and execute an XPath? This would be too expensive and not scalable
- Consume the XML and insert it into a database that has been modeled to respect the XML's schema? Then just do regular SQL queries to get the data I need?
- Use an XML database?
- Would XQuery be an option?

This needs to be part of an PHP/MySQL solution.

Comment: How often do you need to do this? Are you getting one batch you need to process, or will this be ongoing? I personally would opt to model them in a database and ingest them to do SQL operations over.

Comment: import in to db, seems like a good plan to me

Comment: I expect updates regularly. And the XML files will grow overtime (as the updates do not overwrite the old XML files, new files will be added over time, etc.). Importing into a database seems painful. I would need to understand the schema and appropriately convert that into database terms -- and with all the tags, attributes, "1 or more" / "0 or 1" / "0 or more" rules in the XML -- I expect this to be a painful experience. Any other less painful solutions?

Comment: I suggest putting the data in a document oriented db like Solr or CouchDB.

Comment: Would that allow me to query the XML files?

Answer (score 1):

Take your XML files and insert them into [eXist-db](http://www.exist-db.org). You can insert these easily from PHP by doing either a HTTP POST or PUT against their REST API (depending on your needs). If you insert them into the same `collection` you can then from PHP do a HTTP GET or POST sending an XQuery that queries all of the documents from the same collection, for example.:

```
collection("/db/your-collection-of-documents")//name[parent::element()/publish_date gt "2014-006-14"]
```

If you can be more specific about your XML, I could update this question with the REST URI that you would need to use, and an appropriate XQuery.

Comment: I'm still studying the XML documents. Right now, I'm just trying to figure out what to do with all the documents I'm going to get -- and how to get the data I'm going to need. I'll investigate eXist-db. Do you think mapping the XML to a RDBMS is a bad idea?

Comment: Mapping any sort of slightly complex XML to an RDBMS is almost always a bad idea! However if you have very simple XML which represents maybe just one or two tables of key/values then it may be easy enough... assuming that the structure of your XML never changes.

Comment: Why eXist-db over Solr or CouchDB as suggested by other commenter?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, Solr is not a database, it is an index, it also does not allow you to execute XPath or XQuery to query a collection of documents. CouchDB is a document database, but you would need to convert your XML documents into JSON and also write your own application to query them.

Comment: So Solr for search engines. CouchDB would need XML->JSON conversion (which I assume is not straightforward). eXist-db just allows me to store the XML files and query them directly? Are there alternatives to eXist-db that might be simpler to set up? Is there a way to just query all the files without having to store them in a database of sorts?

Comment: Alternatives to eXist-db include BaseX (http://basex.org) and Sedna (http://sedna.org), the reason that I suggested eXist-db is because it has good indexing and a simple REST API which also allows you to submit queries. Another option is to integrate with Saxon (http://www.saxonica.com/html/saxon-c/index.html) and keep the files on the filesystem, depending on the number of files and size, you may have performance problems there though as it does not have persistent indexes.